# java regular expression for negate the string

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to make the build fail if there is any failure in the TeamCity build log.

When the build passes it shows:

> scenarios (5 passed)

or:

> scenario (1 passed)

I need to replace that integer as it can be any number starting from 1 to any integer value say 1000 etc... with `\d+`

Then I try to code 'if these above regular expression does not appear then make the build fail'.

I tried `^(scenario (\\d+ passed)|scenarios (\\d+ passed))` but it's not working.

Comment: what's your expeted output?

Comment: Please provide more input. How are you trying to apply the regex? If you're using java then try to find the regex and fail if you don't.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape your parentheses as well. This regex should match your input:

```
^scenarios? \\(\\d+ passed\\)
```

See it online: http://regexr.com/3b1ud

Edit: The questionmark after `s` in scenarios makes the s optional.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the parenthesis.
I propose: `^scenarios* \\(\\d+ passed\\)$`